# Perl date difference which are in different formats

Tags: perl

I have two dates as below in my perl code-

```
my $asof_date;
chomp($asof_date = `date +'%m/%d/%Y'`);
```

And another date coming from sql table as -
`$date = $syb_row[3];`

```
here $date is in the form of "Dec 20 2013 12:00AM"
```

Now my help is to calculate the maturity-where maturity is difference in days between two dates(i.e $asof_date & $date in above case) divided by 365.

And yes I have limited module installed as parsedate is not installed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use back ticks.  Use localtime and timelocal functions to get the date. Convert to epoch and back to do your calculations.

Comment: When formats or TZ's differ, the first thing to do is always normalize them to the same internal format, and UTC. http://blog.plover.com/2013/12/#dt-sucks

Comment: "I have limited module installed" - You should fix that first :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

...;

my $db_parse = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%B %d %Y %R%p',
    locale    => 'en_US',
    time_zone => 'America/New York', ### Olson TZ name
);

my $asof_date = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
my $db_date = $db_parse->parse_datetime($syb_row[3]);

my $maturity = $asof_date->delta_days($db_date)->days / 365;
```

Comment: thanks,but what "->" implies in $asof_date->delta_days($db_date)->days / 365; ? And for the above to work ,I must require Datetime module installed for this ?

Comment: It's a method call. c/f http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html#Methods. And yes, you'd need DateTime (and DateTime::Format::Strptime)

Comment: Thanks!!!If DateTime::Format::Strptime is not installed,either I need to install or any other workaround?